# Flutter - How to show a timer running for 60 seconds inside a Text()

Tags: timer, flutter

I am building an app that will need to show a timer inside a Text(), with duration of 60 seconds, when the screen opens, the timer starts from 0 to 60 seconds automatically inside a Text().

I tried to use [Time Builder lib](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_builder#-readme-tab-) but I have no ideia how to get the time (minutes and seconds) running to put inside the Text().

```
class ClockWidget extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TimerBuilder.periodic(Duration(seconds: 60),
      builder: (context) {
        return Text("00:00");
      }
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Try with `return Text("${DateTime.now()}");`

Comment: But with this I will only get the current date and time, I need a custom timer that will count from 00:00 to 00:60.

Comment: it will show from 00 to 59 not 60 . i minute have only 60 seconds

Comment: Yep, but If use DateTime.now it will show the current time, what if it's like 1:20:40, I don't want to show random numbers, I need to show 00:00 - 00:59 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use AnimatedBuilder to solve my problem.

```
  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${(duration.inSeconds  % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

AnimatedBuilder(
              animation: controller,
              builder: (context, child){
                return Text(
                  timerString,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ) ,
                );
              }
          ),
```

Answer (score 1):

From 0 to 60 upon a button click.

```
Timer _timer;
int _start = 0;

void startTimer() {
  const oneSec = const Duration(seconds: 1);
  _timer = new Timer.periodic(
      oneSec,
      (Timer timer) => setState(() {
            if (_start > 60) {
              timer.cancel();
            } else {
              _start = _start + 1;
            }
          }));
}

@override
void dispose() {
  _timer.cancel();
  super.dispose();
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Timer test")),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              startTimer();
            },
            child: Text("start"),
          ),
          Text("$_start")
        ],
      ));
}
```

Comment: I needed 0 to 60.

Comment: Edit from 0 to 60.

Comment: I updated my description because I think I didn't explain very well, I tried with Text("$_start") but I only get "Instance of '_Timer'".